# ASUS pce N15 - Low speed

Tags: wireless, drivers, asus, realtek

I have this wireless controller **Asus pce-n15** which I can't configure correctly in Ubuntu 14.04.

I have the latest drivers from Realtek installed and tried the best I could so far.

Still my connection can't have a higher download rate than 3-4 Mbps, where in my laptop in the same physical place I achieve around 40 Mbps.
The most weird of all my upload speed can get around 8 Mbps.

Anyone can help me about this? I'm new to Ubuntu so please be kind with words ;)

Comment: Which realtek drivers you installed? And how do we know it is a Realtek device. What is `lsusb` output?

Comment: I know from the other issue related posts that this device is an realtek device and the lspci(in my case is):
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

Comment: Ive the drivers from this page installed tried both already:
http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the encryption method.
Had the same problem. Try different encryption methods for your router and see if it helps in any way.

Comment: I've tried AES and TKIP and AES solo, but nothing that i noticed have changed :(